# recognizing QR codes with the Computer Vision API

Tags: xamarin.forms, computer-vision

I'm in the design stages of writing a Xamarin Forms app that will process camera pictures of legal documents.  Is it possible to use the Computer Vision API to detect QR codes and parse them?

Comment: do you want to scan the codes directly from the camera (if so, use a pkg like ZXing.Net.Mobile), or do you want to scan images *after* they have already been taken?

Comment: No.  In this case we're using the camera to take photos of delivery documents (the entire document) and need something to recognize the QR code if one is inside the image, and make a rest call to associate the image with an ID in the QR code.  The application has to be smart enough to reject images that are not of the documents we're looking at.

Comment: I don't see anything in the Azure Computer Vision docs that mentions QR codes.  However, there appear to be lots of libraries out there that will do it.  It appears that ZXing may even be able to handle it, although I've never used it with a pre-existing image.

Comment: I didn't find anything either.  I appreciate you looking!  BTW I used the ZXing package for a while for another QR code app I wrote.  Didn't work well.  I evaluated Manatee Works and it performs magnitudes better.  Sort of expensive but you get what you pay for.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing and reviewed the documentation again, but didn't find any suitable operation within Computer Vision up to version 2.1. In the end I settled for this service: http://goqr.me/api/ which does exactly that and seems to work quite well. I tried ZXing, too, but with unsatisfactory results.

Hope that helps.

Joerg.